# How to not submit a form when input is not valid.

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to prevent a form from submitting when the "Name" field is not filled in, but it continues to submit, even when the submitForm function returns false. The submitForm function turns the Name field yellow when the user fails to input a name (I can see when I press back on the browser), but the alert never appears, and the form still submits. Any ideas?

```
function submitForm() {
var valid = true;
var rform = document.forms[0];

if (testLength(rform.name)==false) valid=false;


if ((rform.member[0].checked || rform.member[1].checked)== false) {
  rform.member[0].style.backgroundColor="yellow";
  rform.member[1].style.backgroundColor="yellow";
  valid=false;
}

if (valid == false) alert("Enter all required information in the appropriate format");

return valid;
}
```

And the form.

```
<form id="reg" method="GET" action="processorder.php">
<input id="btnSubmit" type="submit" value="Submit Form" onclick="return submitForm();"/></p>
```

Comment: Do you get any error in your console?

Comment: Have you tried putting the validation on the forms onsubmit event rather than the submit button?

Comment: Right do the `onsubmit` attribute.  Also, it's generally better do default the validity to `false` and only make it true when it gets to a certain point.

Comment: If you're using chrome, you may need to enable "Preserve log upon navigation" in the dev tools settings in order to see errors.

Comment: I get no errors. I just tried putting the validation on the forms onsubmit event, and it didn't work. @vol7ron, I'll keep that in mind. I'm using firefox.

Comment: @ForestHughes you may need to show a working example somewhere.  From what you've shown it should work

Answer (score 2):

Try the onsubmit event of the form element instead:

```
<form id="reg" method="GET" onsubmit="return submitForm();" action="processorder.php">
    <input id="btnSubmit" type="submit" value="Submit Form"/></p>
</form>
```

Comment: Yeah. Seriously, I have no idea why this doesn't work. It's always telling me that submitForm is undefined. But it works when i attach it to the window object: http://jsfiddle.net/k7uSj/

Comment: Oh, you can also use jQuerys [submit](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) event which is far better than inline javascript and tends to work on every browser.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. What do you mean by "attaching it to the window object"? I'm not extremely familiar with html/javascript.

Comment: I mean adding the function as a property of the window object by writing `window.submitForm = function () {...}` (take a look at my example above). However, this is the default scope thus writing just `function submitForm() {...}` outside of any function also adds submitForm to the window object.